# Where to put Mako filters

Tags: python, mako

I have written a Mako filter that adds HTML linebreaks:

```
<%!
    def makelinebreaks(text):
        return text.replace("\r", "<br/>")
%>
```

It works if I put it in the template file. But if I want to use it in several templates then I must redeclare it. Is there any file where I could put the code so that the filter is in scope of all my templates instead of putting as a script in every template it is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have defined this filter in a template called `filters.mako`.  Then in templates that wish to use the filter, simply import `filters.mako` using a [`<%namespace>`](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html#namespace) tag

```
<%namespace file="filters.mako" import="*"/>
```

This is equivalent to a `from filters import *` construct in Python.  You could also import just the names you want with

```
<%namespace file="filters.mako" import="makelinebreaks"/>
```

Or, for something equivalent to `import filters` use:

```
<%namespace file="filters.mako" name="filters"/>
```

Now you can use your filter as `filters. makelinebreaks`

```
${something | filters.makelinebreaks}
```